# Import key configuration error -- simple problem?

Tags: python, customization, import

I'm interested in using Blender as a video editing software.
I found a decent tutorial introducing that topic and providing really useful key configuration file, which helps using Blender with a workflow similar to Final Cut Pro.

My problem is -- importing that particular configuration file ends each time with this error:
[image: key configuration import error]

Here's a transcription of the essentials:

```
File "...\Blender\2.72\scripts\modules\bpy\utils.py", line 509, in keyconfig_set
    {"_file_":filepath})

File "...\FCP_KeyPreset.py", line 118, in <module>
   kmi.properties.left_right = False

TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: expected a string enum, not bool
```

Known facts:

- I run Blender 2.72b on Windows 8.1 x64.
- My Blender is fresh and clean -- I tried to import my key configuration moments after I installed Blender.
- Author of the file is a Mac user and he definitely used older version of Blender, but I don't know which version.

The file can be found here: [download link for key configuration file](http://processdiary.com/content/).
It might be worth noticing, that this preset is a part of a video tutorial, which can be found here: [Video Editing in Blender - Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te9HFQVaSUE)

halp plox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change made in blender 2.72.

The select operator in the sequencer used to use a boolean value (True or False) to select before or after the current frame.

Now in 2.72 it can use 'NONE' 'LEFT' 'RIGHT' or 'MOUSE'. While the boolean values can be entered as True and False the enumerated values need to be in a quoted string.

I believe to get the closest match would be -

Find instances of

```
kmi.properties.left_right = True
```

and replace them with

```
kmi.properties.left_right = 'MOUSE'
```

and replace

```
kmi.properties.left_right = False
```

with

```
kmi.properties.left_right = 'NONE'
```

Of course you may want to experiment and adjust it as desired.